# entity_manager_save_after VS controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after

Tags: magento2, event-observer

What are pros and cons for observing following events?

- entity_manager_save_after
- controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after

Which one is better to use and why?
And which one is better if I need to make a list of modified fields of the saved object?

Comment: does my answer, answers or helps your question?

Answer (score 2):

Both `entity_manager_save_after` & `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` are very different from each other.

`entity_manager_save_after` will observe any changes being made to all entities represented in `eav_entity_type`, while `controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after` will observe changes to products only and when being saved via the controller. This means if you save the product programmatically the observer will not work.

> Which one is better to use and why?

They are different from each other, with more or less different purposes.

> And which one is better if I need to make a list of modified fields of the saved object?

If you're talking about products, as far I know there isn't any before event for product saves, you can't use the after event because it doesn't give you what was stored to compare with what is to be stored. You might want to create a plugin to the `beforeSave()` of the product model, this will be specific for product entities.

Alternatively you can create you're own custom event. There is a ton of approaches to this, it just a matter of figuring out which one will be more efficient.